# Is it possible to change the URL request on a WebSocket connection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I am trying to change the URL request on an already connected socket but I can't figure out how or if it is even possible.

I am working with the [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Websockets_API) and [CoinCap](https://docs.coincap.io/?version=latest#37dcec0b-1f7b-4d98-b152-0217a6798058).

What I am doing right now is closing the connection and creating a new one with the new parameters.

```
// Create a new WS connection
const webSocketURL = `wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=${loadedKeys}`

// loadedKeys could be a string of one coin (e.g. bitcoin) or an array
// or an array (e.g. bitcoin,ethereum,monero,litecoin), has to be dynamic.
pricesWs = new WebSocket(webSocketURL);

pricesWs.onopen = function () {
    console.log(`conected: ${pricesWs.readyState}`)
}

pricesWs.onmessage = function (msg) {
    handleUpdateCB(msg.data);
}

// then when I need to receive different coin prices
// I close the connection and reopen a new one.

anotherFunction() {
    pricesWs.close();
    pricesWs = new WebSocket(aNewWebSocketURL);
}
```

I tried sending parameters as messages with send() function without success, I keep receiving the same data, let's say I first connect asking for bitcoin and the I want to receive bitcoin and ethereum I tried this

```
pricesWs = new WebSocket(`wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=bitcoin);

//then tried
pricesWs.send(bitcoin,ethereum)
```

this doesn't work, I also tried sending as JSON but I kept getting the same data just for the first query(bitcoin)

UPDATE:
This is the the Git for the app, if you are interested seeing the whole thing together.

[Git](https://github.com/ryansegus/gold-money)

UPDATE 2:
I created this [pen](https://codepen.io/ryansegus/pen/PoYmZQp) to make it easier to understand, note that the pen is made on VueJS, but that isn't important. The important part is on line 60 JS panel

Comment: whats the point in this? are you trying to basically like... redirect to another URL?

Comment: No, there is a table that loads different criptos, and I need to update the prices on real time, I could use assets=ALL and keep tracking of everything but I guess is not worth it since I won’t need that many.

Comment: oh ok, but if your visualizing all the assets, couldnt you just "hide" the assets you dont want to see? Im assuming your using some kind of HTML or markup to visualize this, so use css

Comment: No, you don’t get it... check the Git, essentially the user will search for any coin, then when he click it will populate a table, then this table needs to update prices on real time, that’s when WebSocket comes in. So if the user had load 3 coins I just need data for these 3, each time user insert new coins on table query needs to change

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you want to switch the URL?

According to the coin cap documentation, you can request information about multiple crypto currency at once. Is it not an option for you?

Generally you should avoid opening and closing connections to a socket as there is slight latency albeit very insignificant. Leaving the connection open is better since you will be notified if price is changed for any of the currencies you are interested it.

Comment: Yes, but I don’t know which coin will be needed till the user click a list to populate a table, because of this it needs to be dynamic, I lol update the question and post the Git so people can see the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your original question "Is it possible to change URL for a web socket connection?" is no! You can't change URL however you can create as many connections as you need. In your case you are closing the connection and opening it immediately but in the comments I noticed that you mentioned that it is based on user interaction. You can open connection just for the currencies you care about when user requests it and keep the connection opened until user switches the  currency again because at that point you'll probably switch to another currency.

I also agree with @Taylor Spark, you can also just hide the dom for the currencies user don't care and render the ones they are interested in.